# addAttributeToFilter not filtering on product collection

Tags: collection, product-collection, ce-1.8.1.0

i made a custom template for homepage on my magento theme (working on CE 1.8.1.0) in which i get a filtered collection of products :

```
$selections_products = $modelCatalogProduct->getCollection()
   ->setPageSize(32)
   ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','selection_moment','selection_rouge','selection_blanc','selection_cdc','selection_champagne','selection_exception'))
   ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
          array('attribute'=>'selection_moment', array('eq' => '1')),
          array('attribute'=>'selection_rouge', array('eq' => '1')),
          array('attribute'=>'selection_blanc', array('eq' => '1')),
          array('attribute'=>'selection_cdc', array('eq' => '1')),
          array('attribute'=>'selection_champagne', array('eq' => '1')),
          array('attribute'=>'selection_exception', array('eq' => '1'))
        )
    );
```

these are custom attributes created in back-office. I managed to get them correctly on the same page with multiple getCollection and single filter, but i'm trying to get all product in one call, because of performance issues.

Flat catalog is enabled for products and categories, and all the custom attributes are configured with "show in product page" and "show in product list" to true

EDIT :

forgot tu put the call loop :

```
foreach($selections_products as $product){
    $product = mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($product->getName());
    var_dump($product->getData('selection_moment'));
    var_dump($product->getData('selection_rouge'));
    var_dump($product->getData('selection_blanc'));
    var_dump($product->getData('selection_cdc'));
    var_dump($product->getData('selection_champagne'));
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

The followings only return 0

Comment: You realize that the way you are doing it you get an `OR` filter, right? I mean `where selection_moment = 1 OR selection_rouge = 1 OR ....`. Is that what you need or do you need an `AND` filter?

Comment: Yes, i need the 'OR' filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this

```
$selections_products = $modelCatalogProduct->getCollection()
->setPageSize(32)
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','selection_moment','selection_rouge','selection_blanc','selection_cdc','selection_champagne','selection_exception'))
->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=>'selection_moment', 'eq' => '1'),
        array('attribute'=>'selection_rouge', 'eq' => '1'),
        array('attribute'=>'selection_blanc', 'eq' => '1'),
        array('attribute'=>'selection_cdc', 'eq' => '1'),
        array('attribute'=>'selection_champagne', 'eq' => '1'),
        array('attribute'=>'selection_exception', 'eq' => '1')
    )
);
```

Refer this [***link***](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)